# flex : How to import .fla file into the flex application

Tags: flexbuilder, flex4.5, fla

I have one .fla file sent  by some one.  I want to import this file into my actionscript project using flex builder and I need to work on frames of the fla file . How to do this. I am very new to flex . I am searching this  in internet with of no results. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot edit a flash file directly within the Flash Builder (i.e. Flex) IDE. You can however access the published swf from within Flex.

A common use is to access assets from a library swf - http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=853. But I assume you are interested in accessing specific frames in the interactive. Different options are possible :

1. use localConnection - http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2008/06/12/passing-data-from-flash-to-flex-and-back/
2. load the resulting swf into a loader object and navigate to frame - [SWFLoader starts to play SWF without the loading being complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921904/swfloader-starts-to-play-swf-without-the-loading-being-complete)
3. load the resulting swf into a loader object and communicate via events

---

```
<mx:SWFLoader id="embeddedFlash" source="path/to/file.swf" complete="onLoaderComplete(event)"/> 

<mx:Script>
   <![CDATA[
   private function onLoaderComplete(event:Event)
   {
        // the swf file needs to be fully loaded before these calls are made
        if(embeddedFlash.content)
        {
            // 2 - navigate to frame
            var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(embeddedFlash.content);
            mc.gotoAndPlay(0);
            // 3 - communicate via events
            embeddedFlash.content.addEventListener("nextButtonClick",        onNextClick);
            embeddedFlash.content.dispatchEvent(new Event("changeOptions", {/* pass on data */}));
        }
    }
   ]]>
</mx:Script>
```